# Can you end a sentence in parentheses?

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, parentheses

I am a supporter of the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People (NAACP).

Comment: Yes. Why on earth do you think you can't?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited to [ell.se]

Comment: It just looked odd and I am working on an important paper. Better safe than sorry. @TrevorD

Comment: If it looks odd to you, try reversing the sentence to read: "I am a supporter of the NAACP (National Association of Colored People)."

Comment: And in any event, you ended it with a period.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

It is completely safe and grammatically correct to end a sentence with parentheses.

This answer contains information related to TrevorD's comment.

Comment: So no one can answer a question just because someone's comment already addressed it?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Please see the discussion [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/answer-was-already-posted-as-comment-by-someone-else-recommended-action-if-any/3841#3841). In short, it's fine.

Comment: @Cerberus: OK; I have deleted the comments. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: OK cool! I kind of understand your initial reflex. En hoi!

Comment: @Timtech: How about a compromise: edit the question to reference TrevorD's comment, and then I can remove the down-vote that is currently locked in until the post is edited.  ;-)

Comment: Correct; I figured you would be sure to remind me.

Answer (score 1):

You can even end with a parenthesis when there's a clause at the end (much like this one).

Answer (score 0):

If it looks odd to you, try reversing the sentence to read:

> I am a supporter of the NAACP (National Association of Colored People).